# The apache2 configtest failed - modesecurity

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I would like to create an application to monitor device network traffic and permissions.

To do so I want to configure local modesecurity, using I [this procedure](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu) but when I install modesecurity I get the following error while installing it:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server apache2                                                  * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf:
Invalid command 'SecStatusEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

After reading this message I go to the file `/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf` and checked line no. 225 there I got found following statement written :

```
SecStatusEngine On
```

I tried to enable `security2` module, but I get the same error after `sudo service apache2 restart`:

```
$ sudo a2enmod security2 
Considering dependency unique_id for security2: 
Module unique_id already enabled 
Module security2 already enabled
```

So can someone please help me in resolving this issue?